# Как сделать фокус при наведении

Tags: css

При наведении на ссылку из главного меню, загорается подсветка, но при отведения мыши от этой ссылки подсветка исчезает.
Как сделать так что бы активная ссылка подсвечивалась?
[При наведении указателя на ссылку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo6d0.png)

[При отведении указателя](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xMCa.png)

```
.bigmenu
li.dropdown.open:nth-child(2n+1) a:hover
    background: $red
    opacity: 0.75
li.dropdown.open:nth-child(2n+2) a:hover
    background: $blue
    opacity: 0.75
```

Comment: Смысл :hover именно в этом действии - изменение при наведение и возвращение в исходное состояние при отведении. Что именно нужно сделать? Из сообщения непонятно.

Comment: @Alex Нужно что бы при наведении на Menu оставалась подсветка синим(1 скрин), это для того что бы было понятно в какой именно ты категории, а когда подсветки нету(2-ой скрин), не понятно в какой именно ты категории.сори за тавтологию
Я пробывал через :focus, но там нужно нажимать, и тогда подсветка остается активной, а мне нужно при наведении.

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно ссылке, которая предполагает быть активной на этой странице, присваиваю какой-то класс или идентификатор (к примеру, id='active') и задаю ей параметры (фон и т.д.). И так на каждой странице для каждой ссылки.

```css
p {
 width: 200px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
p:hover {
 background-color: blue;
 }
 
 p#active {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<p>Меню</p>
<p>Контакты</p>
<p id="active">Цены</p>
<p>О нас</p>
```

Comment: не то...Получиться должно как тут :[ссылка](https://codepen.io/rupok/pen/LjpqEP)
Когда мы наводим на "Products" открывается подменю, и из это мы видим что я нахожусь во вкладке PRODUCTS!(подсветка зеленым остается) Как мне сделать так же?

Comment: там один подменю вложены в подменю, вложенные в пункт меню. По умолчанию событие mouseover пробрасывается в пункт меню (который остается подсвеченным) до тех пор, пока вы держите мышку над ним ИЛИ ЕГО потомками (вложенными элементами).